# GeoFence Behavior in Low Power Mode or with Background App Refresh Disabled

Tags: ios, geolocation, core-location, geofencing

With background locations, if the device enters Low Power Mode or Background App Refresh is disabled while an app is in the background and gathering locations... the OS kills it. Then even if these modes are reversed, it's not until the app comes foreground again that these activities can resume....

But what about monitoring for geofences in these modes? Does the OS stop monitoring them... or stop waking you up to respond to them?

Also, normally when you're woken up by a geofence, you're allowed to run indefinitely in the background. So I struggle to see how this would still be permitted.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with geofences a long time ago, but as far as I remember they get deactivated in Low Power Mode.

Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LowPowerMode.html) is not very clear on this, but they say:

> In Low Power Mode, iOS conserves battery life by enacting certain
>   energy-saving measures. For example, the system may:
>
> - Pause discretionary and background activities, including networking

Sounds like monitoring your location is a background activity. Also, calling the delegate in your app would qualify as background activity as well.

I would recommend designing your app to be able to survive this kind of events, by listening for `NSProcessInfoPowerStateDidChangeNotification` (the Apple documentation page has some nice examples).

Comment: apple couldn't give less clarity on geofences in general, lol. Ya I have that implemented, just trying to map all these vectors / get this information out in public. (Worst case I'll test it soon and post the results).

Comment: when configuring a background 'NSURLSession' config, you can trigger a 'discretionary' setting to NO (your choice is applied to all foreground started tasks, background started at automatically YES). So given the word "discretionary" in that quote... it's possible these tasks will still wake you up even in some "no-background-allowed" mode.